# why the first line is empty and the code starts at 2nd line? and how can i clean the terminal from that first line?

Tags: c++, data-structures

can anyone tell where's the problem when I print out the code the first line shouldn't be empty and yet and the first line is empty and the staircase starts from the second line here's my code<

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int o ; 
    scanf("%d",&o);
    int n=o+1; 
    for(int g=0; g<n; g++){          
        for(int h=0; h < n ;h++) {
            if(g+h>=n){ cout<<"#";}
            if(g+h< n ){ cout<<" ";}
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Given the input "3" ENTER, here's the output:

```
THIS LINE IS EMPTY IN THE TERMINAL       
  #
 ##
###
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to tell us the input you give the program, together with the actual and expected output.

Comment: By the way, the code you show isn't a proper [mcve], as it will not build. Always make sure to copy-paste the exact program that causes the problem you ask about, and doesn't have other problems.

Comment: And lastly you should take this as an opportunity to both learn how to use your text-editors auto-formatting abilities (as that will show the problem leading to build errors), and how to use a *debugger*. With a *debugger* you can step through your code statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: If using `scanf` function you should *always* check the result of to get aware of invalid input. Strange, though, that you mix C and C++ IO. Why not simply `if(cin >> o) { /* OK */ } else { /* error handling */ }` (note: again you should check stream state afterwards)?

Comment: even if i use the cin>>  i would have gotten the same result

Comment: Side note: If outputting single characters I'd prefer character literals over string literals, i. e. `'#'`, `' '` and `'\n'`, they are more efficient as no string end needs to be detected. If compiler manages to optimise the difference away appears questionable to me, so I wouldn't rely on.

Comment: You have an "off by one" error - your first line consists of three spaces.  Just check your logic and maybe work through a run on paper, thinking about what the variable values are.

Comment: Please also include the *input* you give your program, which leads to the wrong output. And the expected output as well. And if you have an empty line then please leave it empty in the shown output.

Comment: Side note 2: `if(condition) { } if(complement) {}` is better written as `if(condition) {} else {}`

Comment: You have chosen output that is tricky to debug. Try replacing the (invisible) space (`" "`) with something easier to see (for example, `"_"` or `'_'`).

Comment: As long as `g` is 0, `g + h` cannot ever get `>= n`, as `h` remains `< n`, too. For `g = 1` you will get one single hash sign for `h == n-1`, the last value of inner loop. So start with `for(int g = 1; ...)`.

Comment: FYI, the proper include for `scanf` is `cstdio`.  The `iostream` is for `cin`, which you are not using.

Comment: See [Disadvantages of `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf).

Comment: By the way, you could skip the part about mentioning your input if you replaced the two lines `int o ;
    scanf("%d",&o);` with the line `int o = 3;`. (Well I'd also suggest meaningful variable names, but that is a separate issue.) Keep in mind that your question should contain *example* code, which usually has trimmed-down functionality, like no longer relying on user input.

Comment: Change `cout << "\n";` to `cout << "|\n";` to better see what is going on.

Answer (score -2):

Try your code like this!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   int o ;
   scanf("%d",&o);
   int n=o-1;
   for(int g=0; g<=n; g++){
        for(int h=0; h<=n ;h++){
            if(g+h>=n){ cout<<"#";}
            if(g+h< n ){ cout<<" ";}
        }
         cout<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What, aside from the gratuitous and non-portable `bits/stdc++.h`, is different in your version of the code? Yes, readers can hunt around, but you really should mention what you did and why.

Comment: Please read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).